# Symfony 3 / Doctrine findOneBy() using OR Condition

Tags: symfony, doctrine, dql

I have a problem with the `findOneBy()` function in Doctrine. I want to use the `OR` condition in that function. Here is my example code:

```
$data = $this->getDoctrineRepo(Employee::class)
    ->findOneBy(['nik' => $code, 'void' => 0]);
```

Is this possible to implement? if yes, please give me an example. Thanks.

Comment: have you tried it at least ?

Comment: my example is AND condition, i don't know how to make or condition

Comment: check the querybuilder http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html

Comment: i want make a simple code, if a possible condition i want to use findOneBy or something just like this

Comment: Just make a custom repository function using DQL or the QueryBuilder and call that. This way it's reusable and also keeps it "simple".

Answer (score 4):

hi you can try use **QueryBuilder**

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
    ->select('u')
    ->where('u.nik = :nik OR u.void = :void')
    ->setParameter('nik', $code)
    ->setParameter('void', 0)
;

$result = $query->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult();
```

Comment: there is a `->from(Employee::class, 'u')` missing.

Answer (score 1):

try this;

```
$data = $this->getDoctrineRepo(Employee::class)
    ->findOneBy([
         '$or' => [
              ['nik' => $code], 
              ['void' => 0]
          ]
     ]
);
```

Comment: what does it mean "not working"? returns error? Return wrong data?

Comment: it's not working in php storm, it's just giving a error Expected: ) and Expected semicoma. i just add it but it's not working too

Comment: wait @alessandro-minoccheri

Comment: message error: "Unrecognized field: $or", it's not working sir @alessandro-minoccheri